# Exception when calling a stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have a SQL Server 2008 database and want to access a table from a C#-WCF via a stored procedure. The proc is a simple SELECT query that gets the row of a given id and fills the result into some outputparameters:

```
PROCEDURE [dbo].[get_stammInfo] 
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @id int,
    @strassenSchluessel int OUTPUT,
    @hausNummer int OUTPUT,
    @zusatz nvarchar(1) OUTPUT,
    ...
AS
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;

-- Insert statements for procedure here
SELECT @strassenSchluessel = strassenSchluessel, 
       @hausNummer = hausNummer,
       @zusatz = zusatz,
       ...
FROM gebaeudeStamm 
WHERE id = @id
END
```

In my C#-Code, I create a commandobject, connect with the database and add the parameters to the commandobject.

When I call the ExecuteNonQuery, it throws the following exception

> {"Die Prozedur oder Funktion 'getstammInfo' erwartet den '@id'-Parameter, der nicht bereitgestellt wurde."} which translate to something like "The procedure or function 'getstammInfo' expects the '
> @id'-Parameter, which isn't provided"

Problem sounds clear, but actually I **provided** the id parameter. I can query it in the directwindow of VS2008:

> _command.Parameters[0]
>
> {@id}
>
> base {System.Data.Common.DbParameter}: {@id}
>
> CompareInfo: None
>
> DbType: Int32
>
> Direction: Input
>
> IsNullable: false
>
> LocaleId: 0
>
> Offset: 0
>
> ParameterName: "@id"
>
> Precision: 0
>
> Scale: 0
>
> Size: 0
>
> SourceColumn: ""
>
> SourceColumnNullMapping: false
>
> SourceVersion: Current
>
> SqlDbType: Int
>
> SqlValue: {7112}
>
> TypeName: ""
>
> UdtTypeName: ""
>
> Value: 7112
>
> XmlSchemaCollectionDatabase: ""
>
> XmlSchemaCollectionName: ""
>
> XmlSchemaCollectionOwningSchema: ""

As you can see, the id Parameter exists in the Parameterscollection and it has the same type like the parameter, the stored proc expects. I have no idea, what might be wrong, but it seems that the errormessage is wrong and some other error occured ...

Can anyone here hint me at **what** I should look to find the error?

Comment: post the C# code where you are calling thew SP.

Comment: can you post the code that adds the parameters to the command object...

Comment: I noticed in the exception the SP was called getstammInfo but the name of the one you posted is get_stammInfo, are you sure you are calling the right SP?

Comment: @dale: I removed the missing underscore from the Exception Message because it was interpreted as an italic-mark. In the call the name includes the underscore.

Comment: Oh my ... I looked at the problematic code block a thousand times ... and only now I realized, that the Command-Object was declared as CommandType.Text, not CommandType.StoredProcedure (darn copy'n'paste). That was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please show the code that you're using to call the procedure.

Your problem is that you put an `@` sign in the parameter name.  When you add parameters to a `SqlCommand`, do not incldue the `@` sign.